# How can we implement Wibiya ToolBar in asp.net WebSite?

Tags: asp.net

Can any one help regarding the Wibiya ToolBar implementation in the asp.net website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much you want to integrate it into your site. Adding asp.net membership recognition to javascript isn't that easy.

But for standard common installation, you can take a look at: http://support.wibiya.com/entries/162639-how-to-install-wibiya-toolbar-in-your-website.

Since Wibiya uses javascript, It's no different for ASP.NET than it is for other frameworks.

Comment: You do not have access to this topic

It may have been deleted.